# specific e-mail pattern control with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a textBox control and would like my users to *only* be able to enter `....@firm1.com'` or `'....@firm2.com'`

How can I do this with a JavaScript function? The function must take a textbox value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var patt1 = "[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@firm(1|2).com";
    function demoShowMatchClick(str) {
        var re = new RegExp(patt1);
        var m = re.exec(str);
        if (m == null) {
            document.getElementById("match").innerHTML = "no match";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("match").innerHTML = "match";
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="match"></span>
<input type="text" onkeyup="demoShowMatchClick(this.value)" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to give the user a textbox but allowing him to write two values only,
You should use a dropdown instead:

```
<select>
    <option value="0"> @firm1.com </option>
    <option value="1"> @firm2.com </option>     
</select>
```

---

**Update:**

If you really have to use textbox for some unknown reason:

```
$('#textboxId').change(function(){
    if (!this.value.match(/(@firm1.com|@firm2.com)$/g))
        alert('invalid value'); 
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rT2ud/)

Comment: This solution also works for textboxes. Cant you adapt by yourself Özkan?